# Problem with EditText.requestFocus()

Tags: android

In the onCreate() of an activity, I've got a call to requestFocus() on an EditText.  Immediately after, I've got the following:

```
    System.out.println(mEdit.isFocusableInTouchMode());
    System.out.println(mEdit.isFocusable());
    System.out.println(mEdit.isFocused());
```

These were just put in while I was trying to figure out what is wrong with this activity... they all print "true".  However, as you may have guessed, the EditText does NOT have focus, and if I try to start typing, nothing happens.  I have to click on the EditText to being typing.

I can't see that anything else has focus, but obviously something has to have it..  how can I find out what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  It was due to this activity being in a TabActivity.  Apparently when you click on a tab, TabHost just calls requestFocus(FOCUS_FORWARD) on the tab content view (I found this in TabHost.java).